# MULTIPLE SPRING BOOT FAT JAR

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Is it possible to create multiple fat JARS for the same spring boot application using spring boot maven plugin ?

Comment: ...I wonder, what would be the purpose of that second JAR file?

Comment: I need to run two main classes at the same time .Since spring boot plugin allows including only one starter class. I was curious if I can create another fat jar with the other main class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes can create like following,

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-fat-jar1</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.mycomp.ExampleApplication</mainClass>
                        <addResources>true</addResources>
                        <finalName>fatJar1</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-fat-jar2</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.mycomp.ExampleApplication</mainClass>
                        <addResources>true</addResources>
                        <finalName>fatJar2</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

It will create two spring boot fat jars